# dynamically enable disable datepick based on the dynamic status of the attached field

Tags: jquery, html, datepicker

I think this might be bug in jquery-datepick.js(http://keith-wood.name/datepick.html)

**Situation:**

I've an input textfield with datepick attached to it. This field is disabled by default. So the datepick is also disabled(well, that's fine). Now, this field enables/disables based on a radio button.I'm using jquery for this and it is working fine, except that the datepick is not enabled/disabled as per the 'dynamic status' of the field.

**What I tried**

I tried to manually enable/disable datepick as well based on same radio button..like this:

```
function enbDsb(id1, id2){
        var target = '#' + id2;
        if($('#' + id1).val() == 'Y'){
            $(target).removeAttr('disabled');
            if($(target).hasClass('hasDatepick')){
            /*alert("enable now");*/
            }
        }else{
            $(target).attr('disabled', true);
            if($(target).hasClass('hasDatepick')){
            /*alert("disable now");*/
            }
        }
    }
```

where id1=radio_id and id2= textfield id(having datepick)

I used

```
$(target).datepick({ disable: false });
```

and also this

```
$(target).datepick({ disabled: false });
```

But none worked... :(

```
$.extend(Datepicker.prototype, {
    dataName: 'datepick',
    markerClass: 'hasDatepick',        
..........rest
}
```

^^just in case someone asks to use **'datepicker'** instead of **'datepick'**!

Please help....thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahhh....

Solved it..!

just used this

```
function enbDsb(id1, id2){
        var target = '#' + id2;
        if($('#' + id1).val() == 'Y'){
            $(target).removeAttr('disabled');
            if($(target).hasClass('hasDatepick')){
            $(target).datepick('enable');
            }
        }else{
            $(target).attr('disabled', true);
            if($(target).hasClass('hasDatepick')){
            $(target).datepick('disable');
            }
        }
    }
```

And it worked like charm!!